# Is there a way to know which React component lifecycle method is currently executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

In my React component, I have a method `populateData()`

This method is called at various places in my Component.
It is called from `render, componentDidUpdate, componentDidMount` etc.

Now, there is a special condition in the method `populateData()` which only needs to be executed when it is called from `componentDidMount`.

Is it possible to know which lifecycle method is the caller, **without passing that as an argument to the method**?

Example code for `populateData()`:

```
const populateData = () => {
   //do something
   if(caller === 'componentDidMount') {
      //do this also
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not pass as an argument?

Comment: I want to avoid the change to method signature as it is being called at many places which various args already

Comment: Unless there's a cleaner way, you could potentially [get the current stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236925/print-current-stack-trace-in-javascript) and read/parse it for the information you need.  That seems like a bit of a hack though and could negatively impact performance.  It *sounds like* this may be more of an XY Problem and your current stated goal may just be covering up a better long term solution, if perhaps a more involved one to implement.

Comment: How about adding an optional parameter iscomponentDidMount?:boolean ? Then you only need to update where it's called in componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default parameter to check if it's being called from componentDidMount

```
const populateData = (isFromComponentDidMount = false) => {
    //do something
   if(isFromComponentDidMount ) {
      //do this also
   }
}
```

Then just pass in true when being called from componentDidMount

```
 componentDidMount(){
     populateData(true)
 }
```

Everywhere else your calling populateData can remain the same